# Remove and add at the same time with sed

Tags: bash, text-processing, regular-expression

I have an variable in my script which I want to change:

```bash
read -p "Enter the name of city: " city
if [[ $city =~ Liverpool ]]; then
    sed -i -e "/\$type\_of\_city =/ s/= .*/= ${city}/" /cities  
    echo -e "Liverpool: `grep '$name_of_city' cities"
fi
```

And in the city file there is a variable with `#` which I want to remove:

```bash
#$type_of_city = something
```

So I would like the same time changed `something` to `Liverpool` which in fact works with above code, but I do not know how to remove the `#` sign.

Now I get `#$type_of_city = Liverpool` but I want to see `$type_of_city = Liverpool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the code block somewhat,

```
read -p "Enter the name of city: " city
if [ "$city" = 'Liverpool' ]
then
    sed -Ei 's/^#* *(\$type_of_city) *= *.*/\1 = '"$city"'/' cities  
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$city" "$(grep -F "$city" cities)"
fi
```

Here we match the line with the Extended RE `^#* *(\$type_of_city) *= *.*`. Broken down it represents:

- `^` - start of line
- `#*` - zero or more `#` characters
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `(`…`)` - a match on the enclosed block used later as `\1`
- `\$type_of_city` - a literal string `$type_of_city` (`\$` is escaped to prevent a false match to end-of-line)
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `=` - literal character
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `.*` - zero or more of any character

If the match succeeds we rewrite the line as `\1 = $city`, where `\1` is the value of the bracketed `(`…`)` ERE match and `$city` is the variable's value.

Notice that we are dropping the value of the variable `$city` directly into the `sed` replacement string, so if it were to contain a character such as `/` or a sequence such as `\1` it would produce (at best) unexpected results or even cause the `sed` to fail. In the current code this is protected with the `if` clause that requires the entered value to be `Liverpool`, but if you were to remove that or relax it too much you might hit this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would replace the entire line with `sed`, where the `#` is anchored as optional character right after start-of-line:

```
sed "s/^#\{0,1\}\$type_of_city =.*/type_of_city = $city/" /cities
```

This will replace

- 0 or 1 occurences of `#` immediately after the start of the line (`^`), followed by
- the literal string `$type_of_city =`, followed by
- arbitrary text up to the end of line

with `$type_of_city =` , followed by the content of the *shell* variable `$city`.

The address specifier you used is not necessary, as replacements will only be performed if the search pattern matches.

**Note** that since you take `$city` from user input, you should be sure to validate/sanitize the input before use; otherwise you are opening your script to a [code injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if the user includes `sed` command syntax in the input.

As noted by Stéphane Chazelas in a comment, you can avoid this by using `perl` instead of `sed` where you can pass the value of `$city` via the environment or as argument instead of embedding it in the `sed` code.